# Tomcat cant connect to windows sql at localhost

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, jdbc

I'm new to Java and servlet programming so this question might be really stupid!
I have Windows 10, with SQL Server 2008 and sql jdbc driver for java and Apache Tomcat 9 and I'm programming with Eclipse for Java.

I could connect to sql and set/get data with java applets, also my tomcat server on localhost works fine on his own. But when I try to get the same data from sql via tomcat (on a servlet) I got bunch of errors.

Here's the code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter printwriter = response.getWriter();

    java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    StringBuilder output= new StringBuilder();
    output.append("<html><body><table>");
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; integratedSecurity=true; databaseName=baessland; user=sa; password=1234;");
        ResultSet result = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("Select name,features from products");
        System.out.println(result.toString());
        while (result.next()){
            output.append("<tr><td>" + result.getString(1) + "</td><td>" + result.getString(2) + "</td></tr>");
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    catch (SQLException e){}
    catch (Exception e) {}

    output.append("</table></body></html>");

    printwriter.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace()` to each `catch` clause, so you can see, if there are any errors. Silently ignoring exceptions is **very stupid**, especially when you are trying to find a problem in your code.

Comment: I did, and I get a 10.000 words error which i can understand:

Apr 27, 2017 2:56:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SQLTest' did not find a matching property.
Apr 27, 2017 2:56:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M20
Apr 27, 2017 2:56:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 12 2017 19:27:10 UTC...........